# How to determine the seasons of the year from a multitemporal data list using R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to determine the seasons here in my region from a time list using dplyr or tidyr.

In my province:

Summer: Starts on December 21st through March 20th.
Autumn: Starts on March 21st through June 20th.
Winter: Starts on June 21st through September 22nd.
Spring: Starts September 23rd through December 20th.

My data.frame

```
sample_station <-c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','A','B','C','A','B','C')
Date_dmy <-c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001','22/09/2001','01/06/2002','05/01/2002','26/01/2002','16/02/2002','09/03/2002','30/03/2002','20/04/2002','04/01/2000','11/08/2000','19/03/2001','25/09/2001','04/06/2002','08/01/2002','29/01/2002','19/02/2002','12/03/2002','13/09/2001','08/01/2000','15/08/2000','23/03/2001','29/09/2001','08/06/2002','12/01/2002','02/02/2002','23/02/2002','16/03/2002','06/04/2002','01/02/2000','01/02/2000','01/02/2000','02/11/2001','02/11/2001','02/11/2001')
Temperature <-c(17,20,24,19,17,19,23,26,19,19,21,15,23,18,22,22,23,18,19,26,21,22,23,27,19,19,21,23,24,25,26,29,30,21,25,24,23)

df<-data.frame(sample_station, Date_dmy, Temperature)
```

Comment: In base R: convert data into a suitable date format, e.g. with `as.POSIXct`, then exttract the Julian day (day of the year), e.g. with `strptime` format = "%y" and then use an index or data base operation. If you want to use tidyverse, have a look at package **lubridate**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Use findInterval to look up the date in the season_start vector and extract the associated season_name.

```
library(dplyr)

# given Date class vector returns vector of season names
date2season <- function(date) {
  season_start <- c("0101", "0321", "0621", "0923", "1221") # mmdd
  season_name <- c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer")
  mmdd <- format(date, "%m%d")
  season_name[findInterval(mmdd, season_start)] ##
}

df %>% mutate(season = date2season(as.Date(Date_dmy, "%d/%m/%Y")))
```

giving:

```
   sample_station   Date_dmy Temperature season
1               A 01/01/2000          17 Summer
2               A 08/08/2000          20 Winter
3               A 16/03/2001          24 Summer
4               A 22/09/2001          19 Winter
5               A 01/06/2002          17 Autumn
...snip...
```

**1a)** The last line in date2season, marked ##, could optionally be replaced with

```
season_name[(mmdd >= "0101") + (mmdd >= "0321") + (mmdd >= "0621") + 
 (mmdd >= "0923") +  (mmdd >= "1221")]
```

and in that case you don't need the line defining season_start either.

**2)** An alternative is to use case_when:

```
df %>%
  mutate(mmdd = format(as.Date(Date_dmy, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%m%d"),
         season = case_when(
           mmdd <= "0320" ~ "Summer",
           mmdd <= "0620" ~ "Autumn",
           mmdd <= "0922" ~ "Winter",
           mmdd <= "1220" ~ "Spring",
           TRUE ~ "Summer")) %>%
  select(-mmdd)
```